# Don't work Rewrite Rule Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to create apache rewrite url :
Replace " ' " and " " symbols with dash
Replace .aspx with .html

For example

```
/forum/category/category name 1/category name 2/category name with '/.../{category name N}.aspx
```

to

```
/category_name_1/category_name_2/category_name_with__/.../{category_name_N}.html
```

I have created rule :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)[\'\ ](.*)
RewriteRule (.*)[\'\ ](.*) $1-$2 [N]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.aspx
RewriteRule ^forum/category/(.*)\.aspx$  index.php/$1.html [L]
```

This code is looped . I don't understand why.
Help me please

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteRule (.*)[\'\ ](.*) /$1-$2 [L,R]
RewriteRule ^forum/category/(.*)\.aspx$  /index.php/$1.html [L,R]
```

Without the conditions (since they don't change) and using the `R` flag.